# Wordpress filter posts between two custom field dates

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I have really searched around for an answer to this and not much comes close unless im missing something obvious so any help or even pointers on where to get started on this would be much appreciated

OK

I have set up a custom post type named "job_listing" containing two custom fields named "dateFrom" "dateTo"

I want to be able to filter these posts using a form with two fields named
"dateFrom" "dateTo"

If form fields entered values are within the range of a posts "dateFrom" "dateTo" then the post should be displayed

Setting up the form is no problem but how to query between two custom field values has me well and truly stumped

Edited##

OK so this is what ive got so far

Below is the form, currently i'm manually inputting dates in this format 24/11/2013
I plan to use calendar input field but i can do that bit later

```
<form method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="job_listing" />
<input name="search_dateFrom" id="search_dateFrom" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Search':this.value;" value="Search Date From" />
<input name="search_dateTo" id="search_dateTo" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Search':this.value;" value="Search Date To" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Below is the custom results template, as you can see im trying to display results from the post_type "job_listing" and then trying to filter only posts that have a custom field start date and end date within the range of the form input

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('job_listing'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);
$args['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key' => 'dateFrom',
    'value' => $s,
    'compare' => 'LIKE',
);

$args['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key' => 'dateTo',
    'value' => $s,
    'compare' => 'LIKE',
);

$a = strtotime($custom['dateFrom']); 
$b = strtotime($custom['dateTo']); 
$x = strtotime($time_from_form);

if( $x > $a && $x < $b ) {$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ): while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
?>

<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Im stumped, any ideas where im going wrong, Thanks for your time guys
DW

Comment: To post the kind of update you tried to submit as a suggested edit, you should append it to your own post rather than someone else's answer. Note that self-edits aren't even subject to review, so they won't get rejected (but please post it as an addendum rather than replacing the original question).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strtotime` to convert the dates into seconds, so you'd be working with something like this:

```
if ( strtotime($time_from_form)) >= strtotime($custom['availableDateStart']) && $strtotime($time_from_form) <= strtotime($custom['availableDateEnd']) ) {
    //do your stuff
}
```

Basically, this will convert all 3 dates to seconds. So it would be like

```
$a = strtotime($custom['availableDateStart']); // 12345
$b = strtotime($custom['availableDateEnd']); // 54321
$x = strtotime($time_from_form); // 3333

if( $x > $a && $x < $b ) {
    //do your stuff
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks allot shortbus looks like a very good starting point for me, ill get to work and let you know what i come up with in the next day or so.